# Using dynamically created buttons in android to take user to another activity with dynamically generated content

Tags: android, xml, android-button, dynamically-generated

I have a list of buttons in one of my activities that are dynamically generated, and I was wondering how i would get one of those buttons to, when clicked, open another activity and display text based on which button in the list was clicked.

I generate the buttons using a for loop (I've ommited details relating to TextViews in the loop for easier reading, it also used some variables defined elsewhere)

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {   

        // create a new Button
        final Button rowButton = new Button(this);

        // Set properties of rowButton
        rowButton.setText("See Recipe");
        rowButton.setId(RecipeArray.get(i));            

        // add the Button to the LinearLayout
        myLinearLayout.addView(rowButton);

        // save a reference to the Button for later
        myButtons[i] = rowButton;
    }
```

The buttons represent a certain recipe and when clicked they should take the user to a new activity "HowToMake" and generate a textview with the information relating to that recipe only. They are stored in an array at the bottom of the code snippet "myButtons[i] = rowButton" But I'm not sure how I would use this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to add an onclicklistener to each button as you add it. Then in the onclick event, you can call the `startActivity` method of your current Activity. When you create your Intent which will open the new activity, you can add "extras" to it (in other words, you can add some extra data which will be passed into the new activity). New data, such as the ID of the recipe that you want to open :)

Example (Untested, but should be along the right lines):

```
rowButton.setTag("the unique ID by which you can read back your recipe");
rowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TheViewRecipeClass.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", v.getTag());
        startActivity(intent);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I used   _public void onClick(View v) {
                 Bundle b = new Bundle();
                 b.putInt("RECIPE", v.getId());
                 Intent intent = new Intent(RecipeList.this, HowToMake.class);
                 intent.putExtras(b);
                 startActivity(intent);
                }_